# Is adding a robots.txt to my Django application the way to get listed by Google?

Tags: django, webserver, robots.txt

I have a website (Django) on a linux server, but Google isn't finding the site at all. I know that i don't have a `robots.txt` file on the server. Can someone tell me how to create one, what to write inside and where to place it? That would be a great help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

robot txt is not for google find your site. i think you must register your site to google and also add sitemap.xml

- Webmaster Tools - Crawl URL ->
  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?continue=/addurl&pli=1

also see this for robot.txt

- Three ways to add a robots.txt to your Django project | fredericiana
  -> http://fredericiana.com/2010/06/09/three-ways-to-add-a-robots-txt-to-your-django-project/

**what is robot.txt**

It is great when search engines frequently visit your site and index your content but often there are cases when indexing parts of your online content is not what you want. For instance, if you have two versions of a page (one for viewing in the browser and one for printing), you'd rather have the printing version excluded from crawling, otherwise you risk being imposed a duplicate content penalty. Also, if you happen to have sensitive data on your site that you do not want the world to see, you will also prefer that search engines do not index these pages (although in this case the only sure way for not indexing sensitive data is to keep it offline on a separate machine). Additionally, if you want to save some bandwidth by excluding images, stylesheets and javascript from indexing, you also need a way to tell spiders to keep away from these items.

One way to tell search engines which files and folders on your Web site to avoid is with the use of the Robots metatag. But since not all search engines read metatags, the Robots matatag can simply go unnoticed. A better way to inform search engines about your will is to use a robots.txt file.

from What is Robots.txt -> http://www.webconfs.com/what-is-robots-txt-article-12.php

Comment: tons of thanks man. learnt a new thing! :). i am not SEO Guru, but anyway good to know things..

Comment: The bit about sensitive content is so poor, it detracts from the rest. One of the first place that malicious visitors tend to look when attacking a new site is `robots.txt`, specifically because people have tried to use it to "protect" sensitive information.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes but many attacker find site via search engine. something like admin panel and ... ;) i think there is trade off in robot.txt usage

Answer (score 1):

robot.txt files are used to tell search engines which content should or should not be indexed. The robot.txt files is in no way required to be indexed by a search engine.

There are a number of thing to note about being indexed by search engines.

- There is no guarantee you will ever be indexed
- Indexing takes time, a month, two months, 6 months
- To get indexed quicker try sharing a link to your site through blog comments etc to increase the chances of being found.
- submit your site through the http://google.com/webmasters site, this will also give you hints and tips to make your site better as well as crawling stats.

Answer (score -1):

location of robots.txt is same as view.py and this code

in view

```
 def robots(request):      
        import os.path
        BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        json_file = open(os.path.join(BASE , 'robots.txt'))    
        json_file.close() 
        return HttpResponse(json_file);
```

in url

```
 (r'^robots.txt', 'aktel.views.robots'),
```

Comment: Just coming back to this as I've ended up using a version of this answer to fix my problem - you've closed json_file, the variable, not the robots.txt file, so it throws an I/O Error on Closed File exception.  If you close the robots.txt file it works fine.